# Best way to output the content i load from ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to load objects with ajax and then for every object make with options.
What is better to do when i load content from server via ajax:

1. put everything in a string variable (including html tags) named output with +=  and put it on a loop for each object,then append it.
2. append an output for every object i load in a div
3. or a better solution

if there is a better solution is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: You should rephrase your question starting with the task you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to display products in my page and i want to load them with ajax.So every time i select 1 category, items will display.So far, i have an output and an  .each loop on success function.My code is something like : output+= ' <div>...</div '.I want to know if that is correct because it seems to me not a nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that really depends on a technology stack that you are using.
But in essence it is exactly what is going on.
You have some array of products coming back from an ajax request.

You want to clear out the contents of the area where you are inserting those.
Then you wanna iterate over your collection of items and using some kind of template generate an html for each one. the simplest one in plain java script would be string concatenation.
then you concatenate them all and insert the result as innerHTML inside your container.

It may be ugly for a start but as you will learn more - you will improve.